# How do I change the date format for a Pandas Index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm loading some time series data in the following way:

```
snp = web.DataReader("^GSPC", 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
```

The index is then automatically formatted as 'datetime64[ns]'

I then resample the daily data to yearly like this:

```
snp_yr = snp.resample('A')
```

The date formatting is still the same as already described. How do I change this into the year only (%Y)??

E.g. from '2015-12-31 00:00:00' to '2015'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) and then if need convert to `string` add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.index = df.index.year
```

Sample:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq='3M')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)},index=rng) 
print (df)
            a
2015-02-28  0
2015-05-31  1
2015-08-31  2
2015-11-30  3
2016-02-29  4
2016-05-31  5
2016-08-31  6
2016-11-30  7
2017-02-28  8
2017-05-31  9

df.index = df.index.year.astype(str)
print (df)
      a
2015  0
2015  1
2015  2
2015  3
2016  4
2016  5
2016  6
2016  7
2017  8
2017  9

print (df.index)
Index(['2015', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2017',
       '2017'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

Another solution with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y')
print (df)
      a
2015  0
2015  1
2015  2
2015  3
2016  4
2016  5
2016  6
2016  7
2017  8
2017  9

print (df.index)
Index(['2015', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2017',
       '2017'],
      dtype='object')
```